# Disabling backups after "drush up"

Tags: drush, backups

I use `drush up` for sites on a shared server and development sites.

Within some months, my inode volume went from about 25% to 96%. Given I have already 30 days backwards of backup service, I don't really need this specific backup.

How can you disable the automatic backups created by Drush each time `drush update` is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the `--no-backup` option with your command.

```
drush --no-backup up myproject
```

If you're you're looking to make this a default option, you can do something like Bash aliasing and just run that alias instead:

```
alias drush-no-bup='drush --no-backup'
```

Then run:

```
drush-no-bup up myproject
```